# The HTML multipart form does not posts if word "echo" is typed in the textarea

Tags: html, forms, post, multipart

I am facing a weird situation.

I have a form which I use to upload a file and also a text.

this is what my form looks like:

```
<form name="frmGems" method="post" action="item.php?gem_id=9" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<textarea name="txtText" id="txtText" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
<input type="file" name="flGemImage" id="flGemImage" />
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

my problem is that if in the text which I am typing in the 'textarea', a word with exact spelling of **echo** exists, when I click on Save button, nothing happens.

let's say I type this in the textarea: "What you do is like an **echo**."

I even do not select a file to upload and just click on 'Save' button.

my browser starts to do something, but nothing happens. my form does not submits and after a while, I get this error: "The connection was reset"

I have tried with Safari, FireFox and Chrome. and same results with all of them.

But if I delete the **echo** word, the form submits and everything works fine.

the thing is that this code is working fine on my computer, but when I upload it on my host on internet, it's acting like this on the host.

Comment: can you show us the code capturing the 'echo' so we can see it?

Comment: Is the `action` URL correct? Shouldn't there be a `?` between `item.php` and and `gem_id=9`?

Comment: Are you sure the form isn't submitting? What does the HTTP log on the server say?

Comment: Sorry about the missing the "?" in the action. the actual code have the "?", I have edited the question and added the "?"

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a guess since I can't see your code receiving the `POST` but I think you are using `$_POST["txtText"]` (with **double quotes**), or possibly appending/inserting into a string with double quotes? Use single quotes otherwise the string is interpreted, or escape the quotes.

[Here is an interesting post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php) about double quotes/single quotes in PHP

If possible post the code used to receive the `POST` and we can give you an exact answer :)

Comment: I thought the same thing... tried that code that way, it didn't have a problem.  Need to see what he is doing with it, but my guess is also double quotes vs single quotes on this.

Comment: Yeah it almost certainly is, especially since it behaves differently on his local vs live server (`magic_quotes_gpc = Off`)

Comment: Actually as I said, nothing happens when I click on submit, the form does no posts the data, in firebug I can see nothing is posting and in the very first line of the "item.php" (which my form is posting the data to it) I have put a `die('My Error Message');` but again because the form is not posting, I can not see the 'My Error Message'.

Comment: I have uploaded a sample file on the server so you can see this yourselves. here is the link:
http://www.thepranichealers.com/test/multipart/test.php
you can test this code with typing anything in the textarea and clicking on "Save" button.
then just type "echo" in the textarea and click on "Save" button

Comment: What are you doing when the form is submitted? Something like `if ($_POST["txtText"] != ""){ echo $_POST["txtText"]; }` ?

Comment: this the the complete content of my file:
<form name="frmGems" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<textarea name="txtText" id="txtText" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
<input type="file" name="flGemImage" id="flGemImage" />
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Save" />
</form>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['txtText']))
      echo $_POST['txtText'];
    ?>

Comment: If possible, please upload a `phpinfo();` file to your server so I can have a look at your server settings ([here is a guide if you not sure what that is](http://www.mirrorimages.net/mi_faq.php?do=a&cid=4&id=48))

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thanks for your diligent follow-up.
here is the link for the phpinfo
http://www.thepranichealers.com/test/multipart/info.php
I have not opened a ticket on the host till now but I think the settings of the server has something to do with it. maybe you can help me find it in the phpinfo...

Comment: No problem. Yeah I think it is a setting with the server. Maybe make a `phpinfo()` on your localhost and compare the two to try see what the difference is?

Comment: ok, Thanks @eskimo, you had put your effort on this case, I have opened a ticket on the hosting company to see if they can help me. if they could fix the issue and if the would tell me what was the case, I'll put an update here.
A will also compare my local `phpinfo()` with the host to see if I can find the difference.

Comment: @EhsanT ok rad, sorry nobody here could help you get it sorted. Let us know what the problem is when you come right. Good luck!